# How can i make this JSON work when i deploy it as a web app

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im getting my JSON inside {} but i need it inside [] so my other app can read it.

```
function doGet(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('14-vl75N4mAv9FdZNHIhX_lhtQ-XY17lOvEnLIjiSwDc');
 var result={};
 var sheetA = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetA')
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();
 var sheetB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetB') 
 .getDataRange()
 .getValues();
result.sheetA = makeObject(sheetA);
result.sheetB = makeObject(sheetB);
Logger.log(makeObject(sheetA))
Logger.log(makeObject(sheetB))
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON. stringify(result))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}  
function makeObject(multiArr) {
    var obj = [];
  for(var i=1;i<multiArr.length;i++)
  {
    obj.push( {
                      "Question": multiArr[i][1],
                      "Answers" : [multiArr[i][3],multiArr[i][4],multiArr[i][5],multiArr[i][6]],
                      "right answer" : multiArr[i][7],
    }
                    )
  }  
  var myJSON=[{    "module": multiArr[1][0],
                   "Questions" : obj
               }]
  return JSON.stringify(myJSON);
}
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

> "{
>   sheetA: "[{"module":"ModuleA","Questions":[{"Question":"2+2=?","Answers":[7,11,12,4],"right answer":4},{"Question":"Q2","Answers":[1,2,1,3],"right answer":3},{"Question":"Q3","Answers":[10,230,23,44],"right answer":44}]}]",
>   sheetB: "[{"module":"ModuleB","Questions":[{"Question":"2+2=?","Answers":[7,11,12,4],"right answer":4},{"Question":"Q2","Answers":[1,2,1,3],"right answer":3},{"Question":"Q3","Answers":[10,230,23,44],"right answer":44}]}]"
>   }"

EXPECTED OUTPUT:same thing but all inside [...]

Comment: Why are you `parse`ing? Try `return`ing directly or after  `stringify`ing the data.

Comment: i did that now and its returning the information but it returns as a string inside a {} but i needed it returns as an array inside []

Comment: [Edit] your question with 1. the latest code 2. Current output(sample) and 3. Expected output(sample)

Comment: `same thing but all inside [...]` is not a valid array.

Comment: Ohhhh, i tought it was possible, sry for the time u wasted than

Comment: What if you change `result.sheetA = makeObject(sheetA);` to `result = [makeObject(sheetA), makeObject(sheetB)];` ? Is that the goal?

Comment: If you want to replace `{}` with `[]`, that's not possible, but adding it is possible`JSON. stringify([result])`, but not sure why you want it.

Comment: it was exactly that thanks